# Prisma postgres database trying to add multiple models to parent

Tags: postgresql, prisma

Im making a set of pokemon cards essentially

I have a pack and a card model and user model.
Then the cards have 3 types which have their own model.

I make a use random to get 6 cards that go in the pack.

So we find 6 cards from the database of all cards.
Now i want to add that array of cards to a pack in the database.

The pack return fine and has 6 cards of various types member,party,policy

I cant seem to add multiple records to the data base.
How can i add an array of data.

I think im being stupid and missing something basic.
The cards want to be created like a post when i add them to pack or user.

Should everytime a user gets a new card. A card is created in the db from the list in the database and added the the users array. So every card would have a unique id. This would be handy for trading.

or should the user just have an array of strings for the cards they collect.

So i would just add something like a json card object to the array of collected cards. Which can be found and removed from the list if a card is traded.

Sorry if im making no sense. Im just trying to get advice on how this database should be set up. Its just evolved badly so far.

```
model Pack {
 id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement()) // pack id
 cards     Card[]
 userId    String?   @unique
 user      User?     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
 createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
 updatedAt DateTime? @updatedAt
}

model Card {
 id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement()) // pack id
 serialNumber     String           @unique @default("") @db.VarChar(28) // number from all cards
 cardName         String           @unique @db.VarChar(48) // name of the card
 edition          String           @default("") @db.VarChar(28) // first second third fouth
 rarity           Rarity           @default(COMMON)
 holographic      Boolean          @default(false) // holo card option available
 packType         PackType //
 cardType         CardType
 image            String           @default("image") @db.VarChar(5000)
 backgroundColour BackgroundColour @default(WHITE)
 memberCard       MemberCard?
 partyCard        PartyCard?
 policyCard       PolicyCard?
 userId           String?          @unique
 user             User?            @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
 pack             Pack?            @relation(fields: [packId], references: [id])
 packId           Int?
 createdAt        DateTime         @default(now())
 updatedAt        DateTime?        @updatedAt
}

model User {
 id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement()) // pack id
 cards Card[]
 // or cards String[]
 createdAt        DateTime         @default(now())
 updatedAt        DateTime?        @updatedAt
}

// This is how i tried to add a full array of individual cards to pack
export const createNewFullPackOfCards = (fullPack, packId) =>
dbClient.pack.update({
 where: {
   id: packId,
 },
 data: {
   cards: {
     fullPack,
   },
 },
});
```